# GLPK.js no primal feasible solution when a solution exists

Tags: javascript, glpk

I am using the [glpk.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glpk.js) library in an Angular application to solve an ILP problem. I have been using the library for some time now and it usually works well. I have encountered similar issues in the past, but I was able to sidestep them without finding out why they occurred. It might very well be the case, that I am not using the library correctly as their documentation is quite lacking.

I construct a "base" ILP problem and then I iterate over some array, construct additional constraints depending on each element of my array and try to solve the base ILP with the new constrains for each element.

I know there is a solution for each of the ILPs, but the solver returns `PROBLEM HAS NO PRIMAL FEASIBLE SOLUTION` for all but one of the ILPs.

My base ILP (in human readable format):

```
p0 >= 0
p1 >= 0
p2 >= 0
p3 >= 0
p4 >= 0
p5 >= 0
p6 >= 0
p7 >= 0
p0 +p1 +p2 +p3 +p4 +p5 +p6 +p7 >= 1
p1 -p0 -rise0 = 0
p2 +p3 -p1 -rise1 = 0
p4 -p2 -rise2 = 0
p6 -p4 -rise3 = 0
p10 -p6 -p5 -rise4 = 0
p5 -p3 -rise5 = 0
```

where the objective function is to minimise the sum of the p-variables.

when I apply the following additional constraints, the solver returns a solution (p10 = 1, all other p = 0):

```
rise0 = 0
rise1 = 0
rise2 = 0
rise3 = 0
rise4 = 1
rise5 = 0
p0 = 0
```

when I apply the following additional constraints, the solver returns no solution, even if p0 = 1, all other p = 0, solves the ILP:

```
rise0 = -1
rise1 = 0
rise2 = 0
rise3 = 0
rise4 = 0
rise5 = 0
p0 = 1
```

all the other sets of constrains also contain some rise with a negative value, which seems to cause the issue.

I am using the following configuration as input to the solver (JSON for the second example ILP):

```
{
    "name":"p0",
    "objective": {
        "direction":1,
        "name":"region",
        "vars": [
            {"name":"p0","coef":1},
            {"name":"p1","coef":1},
            {"name":"p2","coef":1},
            {"name":"p3","coef":1},
            {"name":"p4","coef":1},
            {"name":"p5","coef":1},
            {"name":"p6","coef":1},
            {"name":"p7","coef":1}
        ]
    },
    "subjectTo": [
        {"name":"c0","vars":[{"name":"p0","coef":1}],"bnds":{"type":2,"ub":0,"lb":0}},
        {"name":"c1","vars":[{"name":"p1","coef":1}],"bnds":{"type":2,"ub":0,"lb":0}},
        {"name":"c2","vars":[{"name":"p2","coef":1}],"bnds":{"type":2,"ub":0,"lb":0}},
        {"name":"c3","vars":[{"name":"p3","coef":1}],"bnds":{"type":2,"ub":0,"lb":0}},
        {"name":"c4","vars":[{"name":"p4","coef":1}],"bnds":{"type":2,"ub":0,"lb":0}},
        {"name":"c5","vars":[{"name":"p5","coef":1}],"bnds":{"type":2,"ub":0,"lb":0}},
        {"name":"c6","vars":[{"name":"p6","coef":1}],"bnds":{"type":2,"ub":0,"lb":0}},
        {"name":"c7","vars":[{"name":"p7","coef":1}],"bnds":{"type":2,"ub":0,"lb":0}},
        {"name":"c8","vars":[{"name":"p0","coef":1},{"name":"p1","coef":1},{"name":"p2","coef":1},{"name":"p3","coef":1},{"name":"p4","coef":1},{"name":"p5","coef":1},{"name":"p6","coef":1},{"name":"p7","coef":1}],"bnds":{"type":2,"ub":0,"lb":1}},
        {"name":"c9","vars":[{"name":"p1","coef":1},{"name":"p0","coef":-1},{"name":"rise0","coef":-1}],"bnds":{"type":5,"ub":0,"lb":0}},
        {"name":"c10","vars":[{"name":"p2","coef":1},{"name":"p3","coef":1},{"name":"p1","coef":-1},{"name":"rise1","coef":-1}],"bnds":{"type":5,"ub":0,"lb":0}},
        {"name":"c11","vars":[{"name":"p4","coef":1},{"name":"p2","coef":-1},{"name":"rise2","coef":-1}],"bnds":{"type":5,"ub":0,"lb":0}},
        {"name":"c12","vars":[{"name":"p6","coef":1},{"name":"p4","coef":-1},{"name":"rise3","coef":-1}],"bnds":{"type":5,"ub":0,"lb":0}},
        {"name":"c13","vars":[{"name":"p7","coef":1},{"name":"p6","coef":-1},{"name":"p5","coef":-1},{"name":"rise4","coef":-1}],"bnds":{"type":5,"ub":0,"lb":0}},
        {"name":"c14","vars":[{"name":"p5","coef":1},{"name":"p3","coef":-1},{"name":"rise5","coef":-1}],"bnds":{"type":5,"ub":0,"lb":0}},
        {"name":"c15","vars":[{"name":"rise0","coef":1}],"bnds":{"type":5,"ub":-1,"lb":-1}},
        {"name":"c16","vars":[{"name":"rise1","coef":1}],"bnds":{"type":5,"ub":0,"lb":0}},
        {"name":"c17","vars":[{"name":"rise5","coef":1}],"bnds":{"type":5,"ub":0,"lb":0}},
        {"name":"c18","vars":[{"name":"rise2","coef":1}],"bnds":{"type":5,"ub":0,"lb":0}},
        {"name":"c19","vars":[{"name":"rise3","coef":1}],"bnds":{"type":5,"ub":0,"lb":0}},
        {"name":"c20","vars":[{"name":"rise4","coef":1}],"bnds":{"type":5,"ub":0,"lb":0}},
        {"name":"c21","vars":[{"name":"p0","coef":1}],"bnds":{"type":5,"ub":1,"lb":1}}
    ],
    "binaries":[],
    "generals": ["p0","p1","p2","p3","p4","p5","p6","p7","rise0","rise1","rise2","rise3","rise4","rise5"]
}
```

I assumed all integers (including negative) are allowed as solutions. But the only logical explanation to my problem seems to be that this is not the case. How can I enable negative integers as possible solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I should have just researched the library more. There is an [issue](https://github.com/jvail/glpk.js/issues/29#issuecomment-892361008) in the repository of the library that answers my question.

It really is the case that variables are bound to non-negative integers.

Variables with negative values can be expressed by splitting them into a positive and a negative part.

In my case it means I have to create a `rise0plus` and a `rise0minus` variable and modify my constrains as follows (for each rise variable):

```
p1 - p0 -rise0plus +rise0minus = 0
...
rise0plus -rise0minus = -1
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. I had hit the same issue.